# Using JQuery to check the value of dynamically created textbox

Tags: jquery, vb.net, textbox

I am dynamically creating text boxes in VB.Net codebehind.

I would like to use JQuery to check and see if the value of that particular text field is "min" or "max", then clear the values.  My codebehind code is:

```
Dim txtStartYear As New TextBox
Dim txtEndYear = New TextBox
txtStartYear.ID = "txt" & id.Name & "_start"
txtEndYear.ID = "txt" & id.Name & "_end"
txtEndYear.Width = 50
txtStartYear.Width = 50
txtStartYear.Text = "min"
txtEndYear.Text = "max"
txtStartYear.CssClass = "YearValue"
txtEndYear.CssClass = "YearValue"
```

HTML code:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
      $(function () {
          $(".DateField").datepicker();
      });

      $(".YearValue").each(function (item, index) {
          //Check if value is min or max
          if ($(this).val() == "min" || $(this).val() == "max") {
              alert("Wrong value entered.");
          }
      });
  </script>
```

I am differentiating the text-boxes using CSS class. How can I use jQuery to check if the textbox (with `cssclass="YearValue"`) contains "`min`" or "`max`" (if so then empty the fields) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$(function(){
    $(".YearValue").click(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "min" || $(this).val() == "max") {
            alert("Wrong value entered.");
        }
    });
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abrquy4s/2/)

Comment: I used your code and put an alert where you have "Do whatever", but nothing happens. This needs to occur when the user clicks in the textbox

Comment: when I check your link to fiddle, it occurs on pageload. I need it to occur when the user clicks in the textbox.

Comment: Alright. I have updated the code and fiddle in my post